# Unable to set hive.execution.engine=spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I want to run Hive on Spark. I have done the changes but when I start the spark shell I get the following INFO(Not Error)

`INFO SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.`

This means my hive execution engine is still MR? If so what I can do to change it to SPARK. I have tried many things.

Thanks

Comment: Did you followed exactly the similar steps define here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Comment: Are you running spark-shell or spark-sql?

Comment: Yes , I followed all the steps mentioned in [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started]
And yes I am running spark-shell

Comment: I am facing one more problem now. when I am creating a table in HiveContext. I am getting this error.
'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/test1 is not a directory or unable to create one)'